# Jekyll, how to remove "Home |" from the title, there is no title tag on the project

Tags: jekyll

I have a site in Jekyll based on this project[1]. When I deploy it or run it locally, I noticed that the title is "Home | SiteName" I searched all files and found no reference to the tag `<title>`, so it must be something internal from Jekyll.

My question is: How to remove this prefix?

1 - https://github.com/sergiokopplin/indigo